# Show title linked to document with edit menu in item's "default display form"

Tags: document-library, editing-menu, launch

We currently have our own implementation of the "OpenDocuments" control with an implementation similar to one of the [MSDN blog samples](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/malag/archive/2010/05/13/using-custom-opendocuments-control-to-open-custom-file-types-in-sharepoint.aspx).

This works great for using the "Edit in ..." menu for our custom document types to launch our program directly from a document library view.

However, when you end up on the item "display form" (which what you see when you use "View Properties" for an item, or when you click on a search result record) then the title of the document appears to be just a regular document download link.

We'd like to either:

- Display the "Edit in ..." menu with the title of the app - in the library view the column is called "title linked to document with edit menu" type.
- OR (better yet) have the title link launch our ActiveX OpenDocuments control implementation.

Are either of these possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution might not be straighforward, but you could consider:
 1. Build custom actions (bind those to either specific Content-Types, lists templates, etc.) so they shall appear only on those you need to, e.g. Document Content Type (or better use define your own)
 2. Have a look at the XML file located on your 14-Hive (DOCICON.XML in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\XML) - you see how MIcrosoft is doing it for launching Office programs. Of course, you need the exact same apps installed on your clients machine for it for properly function.
 3. Use Marc's suggestion and some via jQuery scripts you would be able to add your own actions.

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius

Comment: Thanks! Yes, we already have app launching for the file extension plugged into DocIcon.xml. We also already have a ContentType but not with any custom actions associated (will investigate). The tricky part will be the jQuery scripts - do you know any good information sources/links/samples on how to integrate it?

Comment: 1. Custom action adds to ECB menu, target any control, class or page. Use ScriptLink via a custom action to embed jQuery or execute any Javascript into a page.
2. Using simple jQuery approach, you could use CEWP to link to a Javascript file stored in a Document Library and add this web part to the same page where your view is as Hidden. Also Jan Tielens has an article about this here http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2009/09/11/customizing-the-sharepoint-ecb-with-javascript-part-3.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to add the different behavior that you want with some script on the page. you don't state whether you want to do this on many Document libraries or just one, but script would be a great answer if the number is one or at least low. (It's just a question of deployment.)

Comment: We technically only need it for one document library, but if it's gotta be done site-wide then that wouldn't be too terrible. Any ideas on what this script would look like or how to approach it?

Comment: You'd want to reconfigure the href for the links. It's hard to say exactly what the script might look like, frankly. The idea would be to do something like this if you are using jQuery:
$("a.some-class").prop("href", newHrefValue);